# How to deal with non-contiguous range when using COUNTIF in VBA UDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function I wrote called `CalculateOverStrings(Values as Range)`. The function basically takes in a range of cells containing strings, counts each one matched against various conditions, like does it contain the letter "A", etc., and returns a string value. I am running into an issue where I am only getting the count of the first element in the range matching the conditions.

How I call it: `CalculateOverStrings(INDIRECT({"A1", "B2", "D4"})`. In this case, it will only return a COUNTIF result looking at "A1".

From my research, I realized this is because I need to use the `SUM` of the `COUNTIF` to deal with the multiple ranges. However, I can't get this working in VBA.

Here is my function:

```
Function CalculateOverStrings(Values As Range) As String
    Dim Result As Result

    Dim NumA As Integer
    NumA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Values, "*a*"))

    CalculateOverStrings = ResultToStr(ResultFromCount(NumA))
End Function
```

`NumA` always ends up as `1` or `0` depending upon if the first range given to the function contains an `a` or not. How do I correctly apply `SUM` in VBA to achieve the same result as is done [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countif-with-non-contiguous-range) and in other similar questions?

Comment: Either pass a ParamArray and loop through that, or if you really insist on passing a `Range`, call it like this: `=calculateoverstrings((A1,B5,D13))` and loop through the `Areas` of the range in your UDF.

Comment: Thank you @Rory. This answers my question